# 30days before due date in google spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have one spreadsheet in which i want to save reminder date which will be 30days before due date.

Please note that the original sheet on which i am working does not has columns "Start_Date" and "End_Date" which are highlighted in yellow color
in the shared spreadsheet.

Please advice to set 30days before date based on "End_Day" column in shared spreadsheet?

The below is shared spreadsheet for reference

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AhrpdumTdTjYdENLeU8yWkpNQm93MDJvREl1M3Y1aHc

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

To create a date from the day (G2), month (H2) and year (I2) columns:

`F2: =DATE(I2;H2;G2)`

To create a date 30 days less than the date you just generated (F2):

`J2: =F2-30`

Comment: Thanks AdamL. Will try this and provide you the feedback

Comment: AdamL,when i add said column values i get "Wed Dec 19 2012 00:34:10 GMT+0400 (GST) " . can you please advice what is going wrong in script ?

Comment: @RohanBhavsar you don't like given time? then change format of your cell where date is to show only year month and day